# Iphone app distribution only for selected customers

Tags: iphone, distribution

We want to build a iphone app for selected customers and not make the app public for everybody.

The problem is that the "IOS Developer Program" only allows 100 users. The problem with the "iOS Developer Enterprise Program" is that only users in the own organisation are allowed.

Questions:
- How to get more than 100 selected users.
- How to distribute to only selected customers and not make the app public

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to distribute the app through iTunes you'll have to make the app account based. This may cause problems with Apple's review process, especially if you want to charge money for the accounts.

If that is not appropriate you'll have to enroll for an [enterprise program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).

AdHoc builds have the problem of exparation, the app will only be usable for a short period of time.

Comment: The problem is that the customers are not company users. So enterprise program can not be used...

Comment: Expiration dates for ad hoc builds? Haven't heard that one before. Did you actually experience this?

Comment: Epxiration through the provisioning prifles, the expire after three months.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a AD Hoc distribution profile for distributing your application to selected users.

Comment: You can create and distribute  AD Hoc distribution for 100 devices only.